# Colors applied via Imagemagick are off from what is expected

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to set the background of part of an image, to match the colors of other things in a web browser.  Somehow the colorspace is different, and the colors don't match when using the same hex or rgb colors.

Example: I use this imagemagick command

```
convert frog.png -gravity North -background "#83c422" -extent 307x300 newfrog.png
```

to add a green (#83c422) rectangle to the bottom of an image.

Then I put it in a html page with the background given the same color value:

```
<html>
 <body style="background-color: #83c422">
 <img src="newfrog.png">
</body>
</html>
```

And I get this, where the background color of the page doesn't match the color added to the bottom of the image:

[image: frog image]

What do I need to do to get the colors to match?  Is there some setting for imagemagick to do the colors in the more standard way?  (note also that Gimp and various other things all say that the color given to the bottom of the image is not #83c422, but is #93cb2c)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a non-sRGB monitor profile, the problem is that [CSS colors still aren't managed in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44872). Safari has the same issue, AFAIK. Only Firefox (with gfx.color_management.mode = 1) and Opera get it right.